# How to add background image in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-image

I'm trying to put a background image in a ruby app, I've seen that this question was already answered in other posts but it didn't work for me and I would like to know where am i failing.

I have a background called background1.jpg in both '/pubic/images' and in 'projectname/app/assets/images/' folders but it doesn't seem to work.

I've been trying directly from the html.erb for example

```
<div id="boxy" background-image="......."> </div>
```

but it didn't work. So i went to the css and its something like this:

```
boxy{
   ...
   background-image: url('projectname/app/assets/images/background1.jpg');
```

}

I have also tried using 'public/images/background1.jpg' in the url path of the css

Note: this is not the textual code, its just a representation.

None of this methods has given me a result. Im using Ruby 4.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try in your css:

```
#boxy{
  background: image-url('background1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Or directly in your view:

```
<%= image_tag('background1.jpg', style: "height: 30px; width: 30px") %>
```

Comment: i've tried every way but adding the image in the view with the image_tag did the trick i don't know why it doesn't work when I apply it from the css, but thanks

Comment: I'm pretty new to this myself and two things that helped me find causes of these kinds of problems are: 1) the development log file, which may for example show you an error loading the image, which would tell you that for some reason it is unable to locate the image (so an asset pipeline problem). And 2) In Firefox under Tools>Web developer>Inspector (other browsers I'm sure will have something similar) you can then select an element on your page and on the right see which css it applies to that element. This way, you might find out that one css is overwriting another css instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. `background: url( asset-path('file-name.jpg') ) no-repeat`

so your code will look like:

```
#boxy{
  background: url( asset-path('file-name.jpg') ) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is solved like this

Add the image is the folder app/assets/image

In the view

```
<%= image_submit_tag('nameimage.png') %>
```

the disadvantage is that you can not change the size with size, but you must have the image of the size you want to appear